# How do I build a database on the server side communicating with my app (Ionic)?

Tags: database, ionic-framework, web-applications, server, streaming

I am new to Ionic and going to build an app which can show some information of art of work. The data would be text, pictures, audios and videos. Thus I have got two questions:
1. Which database should I choose on the server side for storing these data?
   I have done some search on Google and it looks like SQLite or MongoDB is a   popular choice, but I am not sure which one is better to fit my case.
2. What api can I use for streaming videos from the server?
The questions may be so basic, but if you can give me any guidance, it would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: SQLite is a embedded database software for local/client storage.So if you use it as local storage it would be better one.For fetching data from the server database you can use webservice.

Comment: Hi @Jyothish, thank you for the suggestion. I have considered using SQLite until I noticed that it is for local/client storage. These few days I have done more search and found that Firebase looks good for the server storage and hosting the server online, so I will try it. If you have any advice, please still let me know. Thank you.